# c++ getting E from high precision double?

Tags: c++, types, double, precision

given the following code I was hoping to use the infinite sum to calculate e to a very high decimal place, but i'm unsure of how to do this in c++, I used long long double in hopes that it would work but it doesn't seem to be, anyone have any clues on how to do this?

```
  1 #ifndef E_H
  2 #define E_H
  3
  4 long int factorial(int a){
  5         if(a == 0){
  6                 return 1;
  7         }
  8         return a * factorial(a-1);
  9 }
 10
 11 long long double getE(){
 12         long long double e;
 13         for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
 14                 e += 1/(double)factorial(i);
 15         }
 16         return e;
 17 }
 18
 19 #endif
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: 100! = 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000, and that doesn't fit in any C++ built-in data type without truncation.  You should be able to calculate e to 17 places (the max precision offered by `double`) with a much smaller factorial.

Comment: hmm so factorial sumation isn't a good way of doing it then huh?

Answer (score 3):

Just do this:

```
const double E = std::exp(1.0); // from <cmath>
```

Answer (score 2):

100! =  93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000

and that doesn't fit in any C++ base data type without truncation. You should be able to calculate e to 17 places (the max precision offered by double) with a much smaller factorial.  You should be OK stopping around 23! or so.   (23! is where you first exceed the ability of a `double` to represent factorial precisely.  I believe 27! or 28! is where an 80-bit `long double` would run out of steam.)

Also, you would be better off computing `factorial` with `double`.  Despite the fact that `double` offers fewer bits of precision than `long long int`, the lower bits of factorial are zero, and so a `double` remains precise up to a much larger factorial value.

And finally, consider computing factorial with a loop, not recursion.

```
double fact(int n)
{
     double f = 1.0;

     while (n > 1)
         f *= n--;

     return f;
}
```